# Чем занимаются стилисты?

Tags: лексика

СТИЛИСТ,  Тот, кто владеет искусством литературного стиля, мастер стиля. Блестящий, тонкий, непревзойдённый, недосягаемый с.

А Можно ли сказать, что стилист правит кому-то стиль? Или это просто высокая оценка его собственной манеры письма, а  вовсе не род занятий?

Comment: А что вы имеете в  виду под "правит кому-то стиль"?

Comment: Имею в виду, что устраняет стилистические ошибки, неточности или подбирает более подходящую форму  для того же содержания (более краткую, информационно насыщенную или более художественно выразительную).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ни разу не встречала, чтобы стилистом называли того, кто правит стиль. Правит стиль редактор, а стилист — тот, кто владеет литературным стилем, или тот, кто может воспроизвести чужой стиль, писать под кого-то (стилем Есенина, стилем японских поэтов, в стиле французских романтиков).

(Заимств. в XVIII в. из франц. яз., где *styliste* суф. производное от лат. *stilus* «стиль» < «почерк» < «палочка для письма».)

Исторический словарь галлицизмов русского языка:

1. Писатель с оригинальным стилем, мастер стиля. Реляция написана не мудра, не гневайтесь, да я сам ее и не писал, будучи не хороший штилист. 1773. Суворов. // С. Письма 27. Как прозаик, Батюшков занимает в русской литературе одно место с Жуковским. Это превосходный стилист. Белинский Соч. А. Пушкина. Не стало более в Риме великих писателей, у него есть только стилисты. Герц. // 30-13 247. В русской литературе я добился некоторого успеха как стилист. 1856. Герц. 30-24 207.
2. *устар.* То же, что стилизатор. Труд покаянный Ге: художник-реалист В нем дебютирует - как техник и стилист. Мартьянов. Судьбинин ...стал стилистом и работает из дерева под средневековье, причем пользуется при раскраске китайскими лаками. 10. 2. 1924. И. Грабарь - В. М. Грабарь.
3. Художник-модельер, создающий модели нового стиля одежды. СМ-83. Дело в том, что на каждой такой "фабрике" занято не более 10 человек: хозяин, бухгалтер, стилисты, закройщики. Труд 17. 10. 1989. Стилистка и, ж. - Лекс. Даль-3: стили/ст; Уш. 1940: стили/стка.

[**стилист** | academic.ru](http://gallicismes.academic.ru/36450/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82)

Answer (score 2):

Можно, почему нет? Во избежание недоразумений его обычно называют "редактор-стилист". Или просто ***"[литературный] редактор"***, поскольку стилистическое редактирование — важное и едва ли не главное направление работы любого редактора, особенно — художественного редактора.

> Реда́ктор — тот, кто работает с текстом, а именно составляет,
>   проверяет и исправляет содержание в соответствии с требованиями
>   определённого жанра, готовит к печати издание (книги, журнала, газеты
>   и т. п.), также выступает в роли управляющего.
>   ...
>   Профессиональные навыки: знание особенностей жанровой стилистики;
>   знание тематики редактируемой области; владение техникой редакторской
>   и корректорской правки; широкий кругозор, любознательность; при
>   необходимости знание иностранного языка; при необходимости знание
>   терминологии; профессиональное чутье: редактор может не знать
>   конкретной темы, но точно знать, что следует проверить.
>   (Вики)

Comment: Мне кажется чаще можно встретить сочетание парикмахер-стилист или стилист-имиджмейкер. Вот это действительно профессия. Редактор занимается, конечно, стилистикой, но я не уверена, что его называют стилистом.